# Given string will only print when boolean is false, not when true

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many of your two bosses are smiling?");
    int smiles = in.nextInt();
    final boolean trouble;

    if(smiles == 0 || smiles == 2){
        trouble = true;
    }else if(smiles == 1){
        trouble = false;
    if(trouble == false){
            System.out.println("The coast is clear!");
        }
        else if(trouble == true){
            System.out.println("You're in trouble!");
    }in.close();
}
```

This whole thing is stupid.
I need to basically make a boolean-using program that tells the user, via the number of bosses smiling, wether or not they are in trouble.

Both/Neither smiling = trouble
One smiling and the other not smiling = no trouble

But it will only print the given strings if there's no trouble.
I get that I'm a fukken idiot, and this whole task I'm required to do is, personally, kinda stupid. But whatever, moron can't do simple code. Maybe someone could tell me what stupid mistake I made so I can get this done and out of the way?

**It's resolved, I'm an idiot who can't read the bracket placement/formatting properly. Also yes, it shouldn't have been a final, though changing that was not the resolution at first.**

Comment: check like this if(trouble) and if(!trouble)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
final boolean trouble;
```

to

```
boolean trouble = false;
```

Your boolean value is final and thus cannot be modified, its default value is "false". That means that it is never changed from "false" no matter what happens next.

By the way, if a number larger than 2 is input, the boolean value will also be "false".
A check to see if the integer being input is in the right range (between 0 and 2) would be a good idea.

Comment: Trouble with this is I am then told that this is an illegal modifier, and that only final is permitted

Comment: Try "boolean trouble = false"
Also, you're missing a curly bracket after trouble = false;

Comment: Well it turns out that, the explanation given to me was rushed but basically, I had put the second set of if/else INSIDE with the previous set, and once I sectioned it outside, and removed the needless if else that got eclipse all uppity about trouble maybe not being initialized, it all worked out fine.

Comment: @MathIsHard the lesson is to make better use of your IDE's automatic code formatting facilities :-)  If you had then you'd have spotted this straight away as the indentation would be wrong.

Comment: The introduction to Eclipse that I received made no mention of formatting, and I doubt I would so easily be able to read it anyhow. I'm still at that stage where code essentially looks like a fukken child's misshapen crayon drawing, just made of a swarm of numbers and letters that I have to take 5 minutes purely to make any sense out of.

Comment: @MathIsHard short answer: ctrl-shift-F (Windows/Linux) or cmd-shift-F (Mac).

Comment: Well that certainly does something. Still looks like an incomprehensible mess but I guess it's a more organized form of it now that I can do that. Oh joy of joys

I do appreciate the hotkeys though that helps a good bit